# how does split flow worked in spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

How does the following code worked? Does flow1 and flow2 will start at the same time? When step4 start?

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    Flow flow1 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow1")
                    .start(step1())
                    .next(step2())
                    .build();
    Flow flow2 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow2")
                    .start(step3())
                    .build();

    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                            .start(flow1)
                            .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                            .add(flow2)
                            .next(step4())
                            .end()
                            .build();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, flow 1 and flow 2 are started simultaneously in the code you gave. In the Split method you have passed an implementation of asynchronous task executor, which ensures that the flows are run in parallel, you can see it yourself in the logs by customizing the implementation and assigning the thread group name.

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("Example");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    int nrCpu = runtime.availableProcessors();
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new 
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("split-flow");
    asyncTaskExecutor.setThreadGroup(threadGroup);
    asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
    return asyncTaskExecutor;
}
```

In the Logs you'll find something like this:

```
debug 10888 --- [ split-flow1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
debug 10888 --- [ split-flow2] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step3]
```

here, split-flow1 and split-flow2 are two different threads.